# Turn color to transparent with PHP and gdlib

Tags: php, transparency, transparent, alpha, gdlib

I try to turn an grey color (rgb: 235,235,240) to transparent in an existing image with php gdlib.

This is the code i use:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:image/png");
$picture = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
$grey = imagecolorallocate($picture, 235, 235, 240);
imagecolortransparent($picture, $grey);
imagepng($picture);
imagedestroy($picture, "newpicture.png");
?>
```

When test.png has a lot of different colors on it, this code won't work. Otherwise, when there are only a small amount of colors on test.png, this code works perfectly. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are not saving the modified picture to disk.
Your current code:

```
imagepng($picture);
```

will send the modified picture to the browser, but you are outputting HTML code too:

```
<img src="mytest.png" />
```

Modify your code this way:

```
imagepng($picture, 'mytest.png'); // save the picture to disk
```

Your HTML code will then display the modified picture.

Check the documentation: [imagepng](http://php.net/imagepng)

You must use this line to store the grey color into `$grey`:

```
$grey = imagecolorallocate($picture, 235, 235, 240);
```

[imagecolorresolve](https://www.php.net/imagecolorresolve) does a completely different thing.

Comment: That i have corrected of course ;) I think the problem is that imagecolorresolve takes not exactly the grey color i have specified (235,235,240), it takes another grey color, that is not exactly this grey color. How can i use exactly this grey color?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you edit your question and add your updated code at the end?

Comment: thanks, this works now. One last thing: When the test.png has a lot of different colors on it, this code won't work. Otherwise, when there are only a small amount of colors on test.png, this code works perfectly. Why?

Comment: There are probably different (but very close) shades of grey color in the picture. `imagecolortransparent` makes transparent the color stored in `$grey`, not the other similar colors.

Comment: I have checked the grey with gimp - it is definitely this grey color. Is it possible that there's no "room" for allocating a new color, because there are already existing a lot of colors on the picture?